# How do I create a window to run my letter grade program in?

Tags: java, jframe

I am a beginner in Java and I decided to write a letter grade checker program for people if they want to convert their grades in whole number form to a letter grade. I want to know how I can create a window for this to run in with a dialogue box and space for a photo/logo for the program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class noname {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int gradescore;
        System.out.println("Please enter your score and round the decimals");
        gradescore = user_input.nextInt();

        if((gradescore >= 94) && (gradescore <= 100)) {
            char grade = 'A';
            System.out.println("Your grade is an "+grade);
            gradescore = user_input.nextInt();
        } else if ((gradescore >=90) && (gradescore <= 93)) {
            char grade = 'A';
            System.out.println("Your grade is an " +grade +"-");
            gradescore = user_input.nextInt();
        } else if ((gradescore >= 87) && (gradescore <=89)) {
            char grade = 'B';
            System.out.println("Your grade is a "+grade +"+");
            gradescore = user_input.nextInt();
        } else if ((gradescore >= 83) && (gradescore <= 86)) {
            char grade = 'B';
            System.out.println("Your grade is a "+grade);
            gradescore = user_input.nextInt();
        } else if ((gradescore >= 80) && (gradescore <= 82)) {
            char grade = 'B';
            System.out.println("Your grade is a "+grade +"-");
            gradescore = user_input.nextInt();
        } else if ((gradescore >= 77) && (gradescore <= 79)) {
            char grade = 'C';
            System.out.println("Your grade is a " +grade +"-");
            gradescore = user_input.nextInt();
        } else if ((gradescore >= 73) && (gradescore <= 76)) {
            char grade = 'C';
            System.out.println("Your grade is a " +grade);
            gradescore = user_input.nextInt();
        } else if ((gradescore >= 70) && (gradescore <= 72)) {
            char grade = 'C';
            System.out.println("Your grade is a " +grade +"-");
            gradescore = user_input.nextInt();
        } else if ((gradescore >= 67) && (gradescore <= 69)) {
            char grade = 'D';
            System.out.println("Your grade is a " +grade +"+");
            gradescore = user_input.nextInt();
        } else if ((gradescore >= 63) && (gradescore <=66)) {
            char grade = 'D';
            System.out.println("Your grade is a " +grade);
            gradescore = user_input.nextInt();
        } else if ((gradescore >= 60) && (gradescore <= 62)) {
            char grade = 'D';
            System.out.println("Your grade is a " +grade +"-");
            gradescore = user_input.nextInt();
        } else if (gradescore < 60) {
            char grade = 'F';
            System.out.println("Your grade is an " +grade);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use java swing to do this.

It is a very basic example to create a window using swing:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SimpleExample extends JFrame {

    public SimpleExample() {

       setTitle("Simple example");
       setSize(300, 200);
       setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SimpleExample ex = new SimpleExample();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can follow this tutorial:

http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/firstprograms/

Hope it helps.

Comment: For my program, would I make a new class or add this onto the end of it?

Comment: For you software you need do a few thing. First, you can create a new project into your IDE, in that new project you will need add a class called ´SimpleExample´. If want make you program with a UI you will need use several UI elements that you need learn how to use like JTextbox, JLabel, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a part of java called swing, which handles windows:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

If you dont like that you could try javafx which uses an xml for storing the UI:

https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm